# What is the proper way to set a user's primary email address using Google's Admin SDK?

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

I'm using Google's Admin SDK to provision user accounts, but when I try to set the primary Email account using

```
Alias alias = new Alias();
alias.setAlias(primaryEmailAddress);
alias.setPrimaryEmail(primaryEmailAddress);
directory.users.().aliases().insert(userName, alias).execute();
```

where primaryEmailAddress is a String, I get

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400       
Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid Input: 387235917385, email.address@domain.com",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Input: 387235917385, email.address@domain.com"
}
```

Is this the correct way to go about setting a user's primary email address?

Comment: When you pass your values into the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases/insert) (the try it section), does it work?

Comment: No, but the error returned is not the same error and isn't real helpful either.  I authorized the API call using Oauth but the error is a 403 - Not authorized to access this resource.

Comment: Top right of the try it section there's a switch to enable OAuth, make sure you have done that.

Comment: I authorized the app using that switch.  Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: If you're using the Java libraries, maybe you can try [setPrimaryEmail()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/admin/directory/model/User.html#setPrimaryEmail(java.lang.String))

Comment: I tried setting the primary email for the user and then updating the user via the directory object, but got an error message about the user already existing.  After some additional investigation, I believe that what I'm trying to accomplish is done using the createSendAs() method of the GmailSettingsService class, which, while not deprecated, uses the old style of authentication.